# Count number of characters between two characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to count the numbers of characters between two characters? I don't need to extract,just count. I am trying to count the number of characters between "-", if there is more than one, they are separated by commas.

For example:

```
1-1-name1         <---- this should result in 1
1-2,3-name2       <---- this should result in 2
1-2,3,4-name3     <---- this should result in 3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you assume the list will be comma delimited? Also, please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I've tried this, =MID(B2,FIND("-",B2),FIND(",",B2)-FIND("-",B2)) so far, but not getting the result that I am looking for.

Comment: @pnuts that is what I thinking, counting the commas should get the job done, but havent figure out how to count specific character in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
=FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),FIND("-",A1)+1)-(FIND("-",A1)+1)
```

I like how the mind boggles trying to type the commas and quotes XD

Comment: thanks, this worked much better as it it limits the count inside the "-"!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced the sample is adequately representative (as seems to have been proved since!) but the following works for it:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

LEN counts the total of all characters, SUBSTITUTE removes all instances of the selected character (`,` here) by replacing it/them with 'nothing', the difference gives how many characters are removed. Add one to get from commas to hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int counter = 1;
string str;
for(i = 0;i <= str.length(); i++){
if(str.indexOf(i) == ','){
    counter++;
    }
}
    console.log(counter);
```